# Error: "Parameter Element is Required" in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, javascript, dem, modis

In the below code I want to put elevation average values in to the list but returns error:

[image]

code link: https://code.earthengine.google.com/6337849ec707ae2e229ba4bdb02e5fff

```
var startDate = '2000-01-01';
var endDate = '2020-01-01';

 
var maxBound = ee.Image("JRC/GSW1_2/GlobalSurfaceWater")
.select('max_extent').clip(geometry)
.gt(0);
 

var dem = ee.ImageCollection("JAXA/ALOS/AW3D30/V3_2")
.median()
.clip(geometry)
.select('DSM')
.rename('DEM');
 
 
 
var NDWI = function(img){
  var bands = img.select('sur_refl_b04','sur_refl_b02').multiply(0.0001).clip(geometry);
  var index = bands.normalizedDifference(['sur_refl_b04','sur_refl_b02']).rename('NDWI')
  return index.addBands(dem)
  .copyProperties(img,['system:time_start','system:time_end']);
};

var modisNDWI = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/006/MOD09A1")
.filterDate(startDate,endDate)
.filterBounds(geometry)
.map(NDWI);


print(modisNDWI)


var calcArea = function(img,list){
  var thr = img.select('NDWI').gt(0.5).and(maxBound.eq(1));
  var mask = thr.updateMask(thr);
  var area = mask.multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea());
  var totalarea = area.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.sum(), geometry);
  
  var boundary = mask.reduceToVectors({
    geometry: geometry,
    scale: 250,
    geometryType: 'polygon',
    eightConnected: false,
    bestEffort: true
  });
  
  var demClip = img.select('DEM').clip(boundary);
  var eleAve = demClip.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
    geometry: boundary,
    scale: 250
  })
    
    
  return ee.List(list).add(eleAve.get('DEM'));};

var first = ee.List([]);
var AREA = ee.List(modisNDWI.iterate(calcArea, first));
print('elevation average:',AREA);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably a better idea to `map` the function, rather than using `iterate`. The former runs parallel and is much faster. Also, as your 'geometry' is a `geometry` object, there's no need to use `.reduceToVectors`, which can be computationally expensive.

To calculate the elevation of each image in the collection:

```
var calcMeanElev = function(img){
  var eleAve = img.select("DEM").reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
    geometry: geometry,
    scale: 250
  })
    
  return img.set('mean_elev', eleAve.get('DEM'))};

var area = modisNDWI.map(calcMeanElev)
```

In the same function, you can add additional statistics to the image using `.set()`.

In case you want to calculate the elevation of just unmasked pixels (in your script you're not, but maybe you want to?), you can use:

```
var calcMeanElev = function(img){
  var eleAve = img.updateMask(thr).select("DEM").reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
    geometry: geometry,
    scale: 250
  })
    
  return img.set('mean_elev', eleAve.get('DEM'))};

var area = modisNDWI.map(calcMeanElev)
```

To return a list of all calculated mean elevation values use `.aggregate_array()`:

```
var listOfElevationMeans = area.aggregate_array('mean_elev')
```

Comment: Agree with @hooge048. Due to reduceToVectors(), the eleAve throws the "User Memory Limit Exceed" error.

Comment: It's true but map function returns image collection but I need mean elevation values in form of a list without raster layers. Accordingly in my opinion map function doesn't work.

Comment: If you want a list of all values, simply use `area.aggregate_array('mean_elev')`: this returns a list of the mean elevation values from each image in the collection.